# Bound Mismatch Error: The type is not a valid substitute

Tags: java, generics, mismatch

**Bound Mismatch Error: The Type is not a valid substitute**

Task: I want to store "Song class object" in ImmutableSet through PlayList class.

I have three classes.

```
public class ImmutableBinaryTree< T extends Comparable<T>> implements ImmutableSet<T> { }

public class Song { }


public class PlayList<T extends Comparable<T>> {
     private Song songs;  
     ImmutableSet<Song> immutableSet; // Bound Mismatch error occurring here
```

Comment: Is that all of your code? It seems like something is missing

Comment: Hi. The Code is very lengthy, I have just mentioned the classes. Because error is some where in Generic Bounds. ImmutableSet is an interface implemented by ImmutableBinaryTree class. public interface ImmutableSet<T extends Comparable< T>> {

Comment: Do you attempt to store `Song` in `ImmutableBinaryTree`?

Comment: Yes I do. But it need to change add(T) method to add(Song) method. Which I don't want to do. I want to keep add(T) a Generic in ImmutabaleBinaryTree class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are adding a `Song` to `ImmutableBinaryTree` song must satisfy the bounds of the type parameter on `ImmutableBinaryTree`, meaning it must implement the `Comparable` interface since the type parameter specifies the bounds `T extends Comparable<T>`.

```
public class Song implements Comparable<Song>{

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Song arg0) {
        //provide implementation here
        //See effective java for appropriate implementation conditions
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: @user3094713 I need to see the whole `ImmutableBinaryTree` and `PlayList` classes.